# Make eclipse console buttons permanent?

Tags: linux, eclipse

I just migrated from a Windows machine to a Linux machine and I use Eclipse. In eclipse, on the windows machine, I used to have multiple buttons in the top right of the console view for starting, stopping, etc. In the Linux version of Eclipse I only have these buttons when I hover over maximize in the console view, and then they snap back after a brief period. Is there a way to make these buttons permanent in the console view on Eclipse for Linux?

See link for image:

[Eclipse Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ7LW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was an issue with the theme I was using (Moonrise UI). I switch the eclipse theme to either Moonrise (Standalone) or to Dark from Moonrise and my issue was fixed!